# Syntax working on localhost, not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone tell me why this code would work on my local server but not with godaddy? I get the following error on godaddy...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/20/10592020/html/foodport/application/controllers/register.php on line 41
```

Here is the `get_userId` function from my `user_model`.

```
public function get_userId(){
        $results = $this->obtain_user_info('users', array('username'=>$this->username), true);

        if(count($results) > 0)
        {
            return $results;
        }else
        {
            return array("user_id" => GUEST_ID);
        }
    }
```

Here is the `obtain_user_info` function:

```
private function obtain_user_info($table, $params, $assoc = false){
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, $params);

        if(!$assoc){
            $results = $query->result();
        }else
        {
            $results = $query->row_array();
        }

        return $results;
    }
```

Here is the code in my register controller specifically line 41.

```
$user_id = $user->get_userId()['user_id'];
```

Comment: I don't understand get_userId()['user_id'], i do it like get_userId($someVariable). Are both same?? I would be greateful if you can explain it to me or provide link for explanation. thanx

Comment: check php version online and locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version of PHP - my guess is that your local server is running a later version than GoDaddy's server. You might have to do something like this:

```
$temp_id = $user->get_userId();
$user_id = $temp_id['user_id'];
```

Comment: godaddy also might allow you to change the version of php you are running in that folder - i don't use godaddy, but I had a similar issue with my favorite webhost.

Comment: @Ryan Ever the optimist! I've never heard anything good about GoDaddy.

Comment: Thanks, ended up having to fix this in a couple files.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, you need PHP > 5.4.0 to access a function return array directly like:

```
$user_id = $user->get_userId()['user_id'];
```

Prior to 5.4.0 you would need to assign the return of the function to a variable and access it:

```
$result  = $user->get_userId();
$user_id = $result['user_id'];
```

But I would ask, why return an array if you are only returning one value?

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_id = $user->get_userId()['user_id'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

This is Array dereferencing which is available in php 5.4
However usually godaddy got php 5.3.3

Depending on your hosting plan you can change it.